# What is the complex Element 'KeyInfo' in the encrypted XML example for?

Tags: encryption, xml-encryption

I'm not sure, if this is a question really about cryptography and whether it would better fit to Stack Overflow, but I try...

In my xml example, some elements are encrypted with `xml-enc`. I got this xml from a customer and changed attribute names and crypto keys to stay discreet.

There is an `Entries` Element, consisting of 1 one more `Entry`. Its `SubSystem` has `Value1` and `Value2`, which are obviously encrypted using the  `transport-key`.

Question: What is the `KeyInfo` after `SubSystem` for?
Does it contain the encrypted `transport-key`, using yet another public key, for which the decrypter must have a matching private key?
What is `KeyName`, `X509Certificate` for? I guess, that `CipherData` is the ciphered transport-key?

And why is there a `KeyInfo` in each `Entry`? Does it mean, the `transport-key` can be different for each Entry?

What does `ReferenceList` tell me ?
Somehow it says: `Value1` and `Value2` have been ciphered using this key. But this is also found in the `EncryptedData` / `KeyInfo` for `Value1`, `Value2` above...

Is there a standard way to interprete this scheme or is it a matter of the application, to cope with exactly that kind of syntax?

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ExampleFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:sim-delivery-file-schema">
    <Entries>
        <Entry>
          <SubSystem>
            <Value1>
              <EncryptedData Id="Value1" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                  <KeyName>transport-key</KeyName>
                </KeyInfo>
                <CipherData>
                  <CipherValue>ccc1...</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
              </EncryptedData>
            </Value1>

            <Value2>
              <EncryptedData Id="Value2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                  <KeyName>transport-key</KeyName>
                </KeyInfo>
                <CipherData>
                  <CipherValue>ccc2...</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
              </EncryptedData>
            </Value2>
          </SubSystem>

          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <EncryptedKey Recipient="CN=company, OU=department, O=MS, L=lll, S=state, C=DE, E=xxx@yyy.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
              <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
              <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <KeyName>KKK.......</KeyName>
                <X509Data>
                  <X509Certificate>cert1....</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
              </KeyInfo>
              <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>cipher...</CipherValue>
              </CipherData>
              <ReferenceList>
                <DataReference URI="#Value1" />
                <DataReference URI="#Value2" />
              </ReferenceList>
              <CarriedKeyName>transport-key</CarriedKeyName>
            </EncryptedKey>
          </KeyInfo>
        </Entry>
    </Entries>


    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>digest....</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>sig....</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>cert2....</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</ExampleFile>
```